# SAPUI5 - OData calls fired fired internally by data.js when using odataModel

Tags: sapui5

I am using [sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.10/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html) to make service calls to the backend and bind data to a UI.
The coding is pretty basic. What I don't understand is the calls that the internal `data.js` makes to the server. When I do the following

```js
var oDModel = new ODataModel(this.sapServiceURL + "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZKMDOCUMENTS_SRV", {
  json: true,
  useBatch: false,
  defaultCountMode: sap.ui.model.odata.CountMode.None,
  skipMetadataAnnotationParsing: true
});
```

I can see two URLs being fired one of which fails every time. Please see below:
[image]
The first is the metadata call which I understand. I have no idea about the second rest call (always fails with 400 error).
The second URL being formed is

> {hostURI}/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZKMDOCUMENTS_SRV/?$skip=0&$top=20

- What  is the second call for?
- Why is the URL being formed
- Is there a way to avoid this call since this is creating a malformed
  URL anyways

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not happen per say because of the OData model. The OData model creates requests based on either the bindings that you have made (declaratively or procodurally) or based on procedural ODataModel.read calls.

Based on the request format that you have there, my guess is that somewhere in your views or fragments you have bound an aggregation to the "/" path in the model. Example:

```xml
<List items="{/}">
    <StandardListItem />
</List>
```

Alternatively, you might have a relative binding (e.g. items="{}") for an aggregation and the parent / ancestor context to be "/". Example:

```xml
<Panel binding="{/}" > <!-- most likely the panel binding is done via code -->
    <List items="{}">
        <StandardListItem />
    </List>
<Panel>
```

I don't think that the request could be because of procedural  ODataModel.read calls, because of the fact that it requested a paged (skip = 0 and top = 20) portion of the aggregation. Actually, purely based on these two numbers, I would say that you have a List with growing = "true" somewhere in your views or fragments (and this list is causing the request).

Comment: Thanks Serban,
You are right. I am using "bindAggregation" on the table but in my XML View I defined binding path on items as well to items = "{/}". Thanks for pointing that out. The code works perfect now.